# Notepad++: Writing a run command using an installed plugin

Tags: plugins, macros, notepad++

I am trying to find a way to take the syntax highlighted text from N++ and then open it within say MS Word.  I have found the plugin NppExport which can save the highlighted text to a rtf file. But it seems N++'s macros are not able to really utilize it. Any suggestions to automate this process? Thanks!

Basic steps are
1) call "Export to RTF"
2) Save to ${FULL_PATH_NAME}.RTF
3) open the RTF file
3) Open MS word

Note: I have 4 figured out using

```
&quot;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\Winword.exe&quot; /f &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are meshing two programs (Notepad++ and Word).  It may be difficult to do totally in the macros.  I haven't had much luck with the macros beyond repetitive text manipulation.  But I can recommend the tool AutoHotKey (autohotkey.com) which makes implementing these tasks super simple.  Here is a little example that I tried out.  Yes it works.

```
^#R::
WinMenuSelectItem , ahk_class Notepad++,,Plugins, NppExport, Copy RTF to clipboard
SetTitleMatchMode, 2  ;find by partial title
WinActivate Microsoft Word
Send ^v
```

This will copy the text in RTF switch the active window to word and paste the code.  It would be relatively simple to change the command to open a new window instead.

Comment: you can also manipulate Notepad++ menus and do something like Edit > Copy to clipboard > Copy current filename to clipboard.